# How do i make Rundeck connect into a Cloud SQL Instance from Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, rundeck

I'm trying to go serverless with my Rundeck. So what i'm trying to do is set up an image with all the dependencies i need and set it up into Cloud Run on GCP.

I was able to connect locally to the database (using the external IP), but, when i push my image into Artifact Registry and try to build, i'm getting errors using any type of conectors :( I already tried to use an outdated conector, new ones, but still no go.

This is an skeleton of my Dockerfile:

```
# Use the Rundeck image as base
FROM rundeck/rundeck:4.14.0-20230615

# Set environment variable
ENV RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL=https://urlofmyrundeck.com
ENV RDECK_BASE=/home/rundeck

# Database configuration
ENV RUNDECK_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql:///rundeck?cloudSqlInstance=project-id:us-central1:db-name&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false
ENV RUNDECK_DATABASE_DRIVER=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# Turn GROOOT
USER root

# Add the Google Cloud SDK repository
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg --no-install-recommends && \
    echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && \
    curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -

# Install Google Cloud SDK
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y google-cloud-sdk --no-install-recommends


# Install Python 3.8 and Python libraries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common --no-install-recommends && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3.8 python3-pip --no-install-recommends && \
    pip install flask requests && \
    apt-get install -y bash --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Download and copy the Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory JAR
RUN curl -L -o /home/rundeck/server/lib/mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8.jar \
    https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/cloud/sql/mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8/1.2.1/mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8-1.2.1.jar

# Create rundeck group and user if they do not exist
RUN getent group rundeck || groupadd rundeck && id -u rundeck &>/dev/null || useradd -g rundeck rundeck

# Configure Rundeck to use the server URL
RUN echo "grails.serverURL = https://rundeckurl.com" >> $RDECK_BASE/server/config/rundeck-config.properties


# Ading startup script
COPY start-rundeck.sh /start-rundeck.sh

# execute startup
RUN chmod +x /start-rundeck.sh

# Change to rundeck user
USER rundeck
```

I'm trying to set up the native conection from Cloud Run into Cloud SQL but i'm failing at the connection. Any help is appreciated.

What i tried to do:

Used different conectors/configurations accordingly to the Rundeck documentation
Used H2 db in order to check if it builds ( it does )
Used an .env file in order to pass the data to the build

Comment: Hi! what error are you seeing? Could you share the service.log / container log at the moment of launching Rundeck?

Comment: Does Rundeck support connecting over the Unix socket? If so, you can follow the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run.